# Reading from a mixed data C++ file

Tags: c++, string, file-io, getline

I have a file where the lines look like this:

```
File root://eoscms//eos/cms/store/group/alca_ecalcalib/EFlow/AlCaPhiSym_Run2012C_B0T/B0TV5/variablesTree_100_1_JLs.root - Run: 200786 - Events: 683159
File root://eoscms//eos/cms/store/group/alca_ecalcalib/EFlow/AlCaPhiSym_Run2012C_B0T/B0TV5/variablesTree_101_1_x4t.root - Run: 200786 - Events: 683530
File root://eoscms//eos/cms/store/group/alca_ecalcalib/EFlow/AlCaPhiSym_Run2012C_B0T/B0TV5/variablesTree_102_1_uPO.root - Run: 200786 - Events: 684342

....
```

Now, I would like to put in a vector all the Run and Events values, skipping the files' names. 
How could I do that? Is there something in C++ like a getline() where I can choose a precise position from which I want to start the input?

Comment: Why can't you just use `fscanf`. `fscanf( fp, "10[abc]", buf );`

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how should I do that

Comment: Try reading this then. http://www.randygaul.net/2013/02/07/fscanf-power/

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand the 10[abc]

Comment: The 10 limits how many characters will be read into the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **all** the lines in your file follow that exact format, you can do something such as:

```
freopen("myfile.txt", "r", stdin);

int run, event;
while(scanf("%*s") != EOF){
    scanf("%*s - Run: %d - Events: %d", &run, &event);
    // runs.push_back(run)...
}
```

Note however that the `%*s` specifier will read through and ignore any single string without storing it, so `scanf("%*s")` will always return 0 unless you have reached the end of the file. This means that if your file has extra lines with text in a different format, you would need to store the first string of the line and use its value to determine what action you should take next, rather than blindly discarding it as in the code above. Otherwise you can have the whole `scanf` in a single line.

For this code you will need `#include <cstdio>` More info here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/